# Mongodb-engine and Django create custom ObjectId

Tags: python, django, mongodb

Is it possible to create a custom ObjectId in a django model that is being saved to a mongodb using mongodb-engine? I've tried to do this passing the string I want into the ObjectId type, Flight(_id=ObjectId(myid)) for example but then this gives me an error saying that the string is not a valid id. Is it possible to override the id with a custom one? And is there somewhere where I can read about this or what the rules for creating an ID are?

example:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bson/objectid.py", line 172, in __validate
>       raise InvalidId("%s is not a valid ObjectId" % oid)
>   InvalidId: short_profile_4fcad5e8e5095f5a4f000000 is not a valid ObjectId

Comment: What is the exact error, please?

Answer (score 0):

For sure you can your custom objectId, check objectId [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs) for that , but i don't unsdestand fot what you need it.

Instead of ObjectId you can use any type that you want. So you can make _id string and insert any strting value instead of mongo ObjectId. But your custom _id must be unique for each member of a collection. This is enforced if the collection has an index on _id, which is the case by default.

from documentation

> Although _id values can be of any
>   type, a special BSON datatype is
>   provided for object ids.  This type is
>   a 12-byte binary value designed to
>   have a reasonably high probability of
>   being unique when allocated.  All of
>   the officially-supported MongoDB
>   drivers use this type by default for
>   _id values.  Also, the Mongo database itself uses this type when assigning
>   _id values on inserts where no _id value is present.

Comment: So what I actually want is to set a string as my _id but I keep getting this error: AutoField (default primary key) values must be strings representing an ObjectId on MongoDB (got u'ryanair-DU...' instead) Any ideas what might be wrong? My model has _id = models.CharField(db_index=True)